# How to create(declare) TextBlocks with FOR NEXT loop in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am trying to programaticly declare TextBlocks with For Next loop in Visual Basic (using MS Visual studio 2012 Express for Windows Phone)

I would like to add TextBlocks with code to Canvas.

My problem is naming every each TextBlock with different name (I want that every TextBlock has a iteration number in it from the for next loop)

Comment: Use an array or collection.

Comment: Why can't you do `Textblocklist(i).Name = i.ToString()` or something similar

Comment: Thank You very much :-) I did not realise that I could declare an array that contains TextBlocks. My problem is now solved.

Comment: Thanks. :) The Array did the trick.